# Disable inline editing for full grid in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How can I disable inline editing mode while I click on any row in jqGrid.?

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {

 $("#toolbar").setColProp('mt_desc',{editable:false});

      },
```

I got this one solution. but I think it's not feasible to add for every column name and add them into function.

Whenever I click on edit button in actions, at that time Inline mode should be enable otherwise It must be disable. How can I do this?

Can anybody please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for question, I am posting this answer over here. Cause it may be helpful for you. You can disable every cell of row while you click on any cell using onSelectRow.

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
      if (id && id !== lastSel) {
      $("#toolbar").jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSel);
      var cm = $("#toolbar").jqGrid('getColProp','Name');
      cm.editable = false;
      lastSel = id;
      }
      },
```

I got my solution.
Thanks